# break from case while inside an anonymous class

Tags: android, case, break, anonymous-class

I am using firebase database for a university project. I think it doesn't matter what is does. My question is clear. Why won't it let me break in case 2 inside of case R.id.first. It is a compile error that just says "break outside switch or loop". I can't figure out what is the matter. I would appreciate some help :)

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                switch (checkedId){
                    case R.id.first:
                        mDatabase.child("questions").child("basic").child("comments").child("first").child("answers").child("correct").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                switch (Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString())){
                                    case 1:
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        mDatabase.child("questions").child("basic").child("comments").child("first").child("mistakes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                                getValue = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                                                getValue++;

                                                mDatabase.child("questions").child("basic").child("comments").child("first").child("mistakes").setValue(getValue);

                                                break;


                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }


                                        });

                                        break;


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                        break;

                    case R.id.second:
                        break;
                    case R.id.third:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` works for going out of `switch` or any `loop`. This does **not** work for breaking out of a **function**. In your case you are trying to break from a callback **function** `onDataChange()` using `break`. This will always create a **syntax error**.

Comment: Oh, i get it. But i need to break from the switch at that exact time. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can set flag and after coming out of that function , you can add condition on that flag and break.